# python call function from DLL

Tags: python, dll

I have a python file from which i want to call a function from a dll.

The prototype of the function is :

```
typedef double real_T;
extern real_T __declspec(dllexport) RectIntersect(const real_T rect1[8], const real_T rect2[8]);
```

The python code:

```
import math;
import ctypes;
from ctypes import *
import numpy;


# this module shall always be executed directly
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Program started !";
    rect = ctypes.c_double * 8;
    rect1 = rect(1.1, 2.45, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    rect2 = rect(1.6, 3.45, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1);

    # Load DLL into memory.

    hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("IntersectDLL.dll");
    hllDll.RectIntersect.argtypes =[ctypes.c_double * 8, ctypes.c_double * 8];
    hllDll.RectIntersect (rect1, rect2);
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 70, in exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "D:\Sandboxes\SRR2T0\06_Algorithm\05_Testing\05_Test_Environment\algo\smr200_bbt\valf_tests\adma\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    hllDll.RectIntersect (rect1, rect2);
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (8 bytes in excess)
```

Please help :(. ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C declaration

```
real_T RectIntersect(const real_T rect1[8], ...)
```

is completely equivalent to (and replaced by the C compiler with):

```
real_T RectIntersect(const real_T *rect1, ...)
```

This means the function in the DLL is not actually expecting an array of 8 doubles, but a pointer to a double, which might be followed by 7 more to make an array of 8 of them (but this part is not checked).  It means that you need other ways to write it with ctypes; for example:

```
hllDll.RectIntersect.argtypes =[ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 8),...]
```

and pass it with `ctypes.byref(rect1)`.

Alternatively: you may not have this problem with CFFI (http://cffi.readthedocs.org/) instead of ctypes, which matches more closely the C types:

```
import cffi
ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
    typedef double real_T;
    real_T RectIntersect(const real_T rect1[8], const real_T rect2[8]);
""")
lib = ffi.dlopen("IntersectDLL.dll")
rect1 = ffi.new("real_T[8]", [1.1, 2.45, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
rect2 = ffi.new("real_T[8]", [1.6, 3.45, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1])
lib.RectIntersect(rect1, rect2)
```

Comment: -cant delete this comment.

Comment: I tried to recreate the posted use case.  Two other details need fixing: `hllDll.RectIntersect.restype = ctypes.c_double` and the use of `ctypes.byref()` rather than just `byref()`.  After this, it works for me.